# Conda installs packages on the base environment only

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I have Conda 4.7.11 and system python 3.7.3 (base) on MacBook. Whenever I try to install new packages on the environment that I have created, Conda installs them on the base instead.

I have activated the environment and when I type `python` on the Terminal, I get the correct python version of my env (3.6.9). Also, `which python` points me to the correct python path: `/anaconda3/envs/Bayesian_Models/bin/python`

[image]

But, if I type `conda info`, when my env is active, then I get this (python 3.7.3):

[image]

Comment: It's normal behavior. To check installed packages activate desired environment and use `conda list` command.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean normal? The packages are not installed on the desired environment as I describe, but rather on the base. Even though, I run the ‘conda install’ from within the desired env. The Bayesian_Models has nothing with ‘conda info’, only the basic packages that you get with ‘conda create’

Comment: Normal means that `conda info` gives you general information about anaconda installation. It returns the same information regardless of the active environment. Use `conda list` to check packages installed in any particular environment. `conda list` -> install package -> `conda list` - what do you get in this case? - add to the question (as text please).

Comment: Conda list returns the packages that are only installed in the active env. And these are the basic packages that I get when I create the env with python=3.6. Afterwards, regardless what package I try to install it does not appear neither on the ‘conda list’ nor can be called from Bayesian_Models python.

Comment: Perform these actions again and add console output to the question (new env -> conda_list -> install package -> conda list). Right now you have provided almost no details about the problem.

Comment: Apologies, in my first reply, when I said that “Bayesian_Models has nothing with ‘conda info’...” I meant ‘conda list’. That might have been confusing. Sorry.

Comment: Sorry, but I disagree. I’ve stated that no packages are installed on the env. Conda list just confirms that. That’s the problem. No packages are being installed on the desired env but rather conda installs them on the base. I feel that this is pretty straight forward.

Comment: @Jespar if you specify the env using the `--name|-n` flag does it still install to **base**? E.g., `conda install -n Bayesian_Models foo_package`

Comment: @merv actually that worked! Could you please write it as a comment! So, I can rate it as a correct answer? Very helpful!

Comment: Actually, looking at this again, I should point out that `conda info` always reports the Python version of **base** because `conda` is a Python package that runs in the **base** interpreter. To check current Python, use `which python` or `python -V`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Workaround

I'm not sure how to fix the issue permanently, but specifying the env using the `--name|-n` tag could get around the problem:

```
conda install -n Bayesian_Models foo_package
```